# How to create a decorator that works on class-based views function and class?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have some decorators that can be used on top of class-based views like below :

```
@method_decorator(auth0_login_required, name='dispatch')
class MyClass(DetailView):
    ...
```

I'd like to also be able to use it on top of functions inside class-based views like so :

```
class MyClass2(DetailView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        ...

    @auth0_login_required
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

The problem is that the decorator doesn't work the same for these two use case, I'd like to avoid creating two decorators that does the same work.

Here's what the decorator looks like :

```
def auth0_login_required(function):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated or request.user.is_staff:
            ...
        ...

        return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__ = function.__doc__
    wrap.__name__ = function.__name__
    return wrap
```

For the second use case I have to add `self` as parameter right before `request`.

I was wondering if there was a way to make it work both ways with one decorator?

Comment: Your title mentions function-based-views, but your question only contains class-based-views. `MyClass2` is still a class based view.

Comment: @Alasdair Corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decorate the `post` method of your class based view with `name='post'`.

```
@method_decorator(auth0_login_required, name="post")
class MyClass2(DetailView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

Or you can decorate the `post` method directly. Since it's a method, you should still use `method_decorator`.

```
class MyClass2(DetailView):
    ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        ...

    @method_decorator(auth0_login_required)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

If you have a function based view, then you don't need to use `method_decorator`.

```
@auth0_login_required
def my_function_based_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: Didn't realise `method_decorator` could be used on top of functions too!